# how can i implement shift() method without using others methods? JS

Tags: javascript, methods

```
// example    
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const removedElement = numbers.shift();
removedElement === 1
numbers === [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This is my code, cant remove the first element from the array

```js
numbers.shift = function() {
  if (!this.length) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const el = delete this[0];
  this.length -= 1;

  return el;
};
```

Comment: The [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.shift) has an algorithm on how to do it. Loop and reassign indexes.

Comment: `delete` returns `true` or `false`. So `el` is either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Grab the first item (to return)
2. Shift everything to the left by 1
3. Unset the last value
4. Truncate the length
5. Return the initial item

```js
// Override the built-in shift method for Array
Array.prototype.shift = function() {
  if (this.length < 1) return undefined;
  const removed = this[0]; // Grab the first element
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
    this[i] = this[i + 1]; // Shift to left
  };
  this[this.length - 1] = undefined; // Clear last element
  this.length -= 1; // Truncate to length-1
  return removed;
};

// Example    
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const removedElement = numbers.shift();
console.log(removedElement === 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(numbers) === JSON.stringify([2, 3, 4, 5]));
```